# Why Octave shows wrong dimension of this char array

Tags: octave

I don't understand why this array:

```
Type = Reflective Event, Reflective Event, Reflective Event
```

according to Octave's variable editor is a 3x19 char array.

In the variable editor, Type is shown as follows (I don't know if that's helpful)

```
TYPE =

Reflective Event   
Reflective Event   
Reflective Event
```

The thing is odd, in fact when I code `disp(size(TYPE))` I get `3   19` accordingly.

Now, the even wierder thing is that, if I then code `size(TYPE,1)` which should give the size of TYPE's first dimension, I instead get `1   1`.

Can you guys help me figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: Hum I use mostly matlab, but your syntax is invalid in MATLAB, that variable `Type` can not be defined like that. Is this the actual code you use? I get "sytanx error" in OCtave online

Comment: The size of `TYPE`'s first dimension is given by `size(TYPE,1)` or `size(TYPE)(1)`, not `size(TYPE(1))`.

Comment: yes, that was a typo I edited thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, as the syntax in the post is invalid Octave:

Your variable is actually a matrix of chars. Note that a string is simply an array of independent chars. so

```
var1=" Reflective Event, ";
```

is a `length(var1)==19` array, or a `size(var1)==(1,19)` array. Now, if you repeat that, you can either make a `(1,19*3)` array, or a `(3,19)` matrix, which I assume is what you have.

Now, as you did not know that each char is individual, you reached the wrong conclusion with your second test. When you index a matrix using linear indices (i.e. a single index), it will "unroll" the array and give you that single elements.

i.e. `A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]` is a 3x3 matrix, but you can do `A(2,1)` or just `A(4)` to access the value 4.

In your test `size(TYPE(1))` is `(1,1)`, because `TYPE(1)==" "`, as `TYPE(3)=="e"` and so on.

Comment: oooh now I understand. It counts each character so one of those is made of 19 chars! Much more clear now, thank you